# 28k/56k modem emulator/decoder

Tags: type-conversion, converters, modem, ogg

I have a kinda-lossless modem record in ogg. The main problem is that I don't know how to translate the data to some understandable form. Is there any modem tool capable of converting the data to tome meaningful format?

If not, what's the best practice to bruteforcefully find out what the original content before modulation was? I mean like generating possible data until the original data file and the generated one matches.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ask this guy: http://www.whence.com/minimodem/

He has implemented early protocols in minimodem but might be aware of another tool for latest protocols.